# Grid. If a div is bigger than x px, move it down to another row

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I want a row of two columns with two divs that I have.
If the divs are too large and start overlapping, I need the second to go down, but I can't make it happen, I've tried with grid but is not working.

The row that I'm trying to make it work is the one with the gray tags. In the first card, the row is working well because the div's text is small, but in the second card the tags are overlapping, I need in that case the second tag to go down

[image]

**This is the HTML**

```
<div class="tags">
//activitiesTag brings an array with allways two items
  <div class="tag-box" *ngFor="let activityTag of activitiesTag"> 
    <p class="tag-text">
    {{ activityTag.name }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And this is the css**

```
.tags {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.tag-box {
  width: max-content;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 16px 0px 0 16px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(207, 214, 226, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `flex-wrap : wrap;`

```css
    .container {
    width : 125px; /* for example purpose only */
    background-color : #fff; /* for example purpose only */
    border : solid 2px red; /* for example purpose only */
    display : flex;
    justify-content : flex-start;
    flex-wrap : wrap; /* Put elements one row below if they overlap */
    }
    
    .tags {
    color : #fff;
    background-color : rgba(255,0,0,0.25)
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <p class="tags"> Tag 1 </p>
      <p class="tags"> Very long Tag 2 </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I didn't even know that exist